# Flash CS5 auto "merge" of two simple objects

Tags: flash, merge

Hey, I wonder how to disable the "auto combine" (or merge ?) of two simple draw objects (line, square etc.) on the same layer in Flash.

When i draw a line, and then a line that crosses it, they automatically merge in a cross. How to disable it ?

Comment: Okey, after some clicking I found a solution, you just click on Cap and select none. Have to learn some more about that ... thanks anyway.

Comment: Please close the question then.

Comment: sorry, I see no "close this question" button. I answered my question and it says it'll be closed in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, after some clicking I found a solution, you just click on Cap (you have drawn object selected, look in the right middle bottom screen) and select none. Have to learn some more about that ... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

select your image, then go to modify--combine objects-- then click on union.